# Google Icon Vertical Alignment Not Working

Tags: html, css, icons

I am trying to align the "minus" and "plus" sign to the bottom. However, neither the css nor inline style works. By selecting the contents, there is no extra white space in the bottom of the icon.

Why neither css nor the inline-style statement didn't work?

Here below are the codes I tried:

**HTML**

```
<tr>
  <td style="vertical-align: text-bottom;">
    Copies:
    <i class="material-icons icons">&#xE15D;</i>
    <input type="text" id="myNumber" size="1px" value="1" />
    <i class="material-icons">&#xE3BA;</i>
  </td>
</tr>
```

**CSS Option 1**

```
material-icons.icons {
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
}
```

**CSS Option 2**

```
material-icons.icons {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I think in your example you are missing dot in beggining of your CSS. Selector should be `.material-icons.icons`

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using a [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) for the table cell.

```css
td {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end; /* Vertical alignment at the bottom */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Copies:
      <i class="material-icons icons">&#xE15D;</i>
      <input type="text" id="myNumber" size="1px" value="1" />
      <i class="material-icons">&#xE3BA;</i>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i think , you should go with `align-items: center;`, it will be adjusted in middle.

Answer (score 0):

Add below css and you're done...

```
tr>td {
    display:table;
}
tr>td>i {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Comment: I think its not working as expected. As an active user here, i would like to ask you @BuggyParadox to please confirm before adding answers here as if answer is not helpful then users may downvote.

Comment: See : http://jsfiddle.net/amw21h7o/ i added your css, but its not working.

Comment: its fine now, i was just saying as some users will downvote your asnwer as they will try and find its not working.But now, its good.

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1 :**

> PS: @Gerard answer is well accepted as it follows the flexbox which is
>   a good technique to play with element's alignment, also the answer doesnot
>   modify the markup as its slightly modified in approach 2.

**Approach 2:**

- Made slight change in html mark-up,
   - Wrapped the `Copies:` inside a `span` tag.
- Floated every element, and used `line-height` to adjust the elements.

```css
td {
    height: 20px;
}

td > * {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td valign="bottom">
      <span>Copies:</span>
      <i class="material-icons icons">&#xE15D;</i>
      <input type="text" id="myNumber" size="1px" value="1" />
      <i class="material-icons">&#xE3BA;</i>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make different < td > for each of them it will align in proper way. Check the below code :

//Link is to add the material icon (CDN for material Icon) you have do add this in

```
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">


<table>
<tr>
  <td style="vertical-align: text-bottom;">  
    Copies:</td>
   <td> <i class="material-icons icons">&#xE15D;</i>  </td>
  <td>  <input type="text" id="myNumber" size="1px" value="1" /> </td>
    <td><i class="material-icons">&#xE3BA;</i></td>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```